# Discrepancy In Amortized Cost Results: Athena Query using Cost and Usage Reports (CUR) VS AWS Cost Explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-cost-explorer

I've been using AWS Athena along with Cost and Usage Reports (CUR) to check amortized costs for the past six months. When I compare the results with Cost Explorer with the [amortized cost filter](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/home?#/custom?groupBy=LinkedAccount&forecastTimeRangeOption=None&hasBlended=false&excludeRefund=false&excludeCredit=false&excludeRIUpfrontFees=false&excludeRIRecurringCharges=false&excludeOtherSubscriptionCosts=false&excludeSupportCharges=false&excludeTax=false&excludeTaggedResources=false&chartStyle=Stack&timeRangeOption=Last12Months&granularity=Monthly&isTemplate=true&filter=%5B%7B%22dimension%22:%22UsageType%22,%22values%22:%5B%7B%22value%22:%22Route53-Domains%22,%22unit%22:%22Quantity%22%7D%5D,%22include%22:false,%22children%22:null%7D,%7B%22dimension%22:%22RecordType%22,%22values%22:%5B%22Other%22,%22Recurring%22,%22DiscountedUsage%22,%22SavingsPlanCoveredUsage%22,%22SavingsPlanNegation%22,%22SavingsPlanRecurringFee%22,%22SavingsPlanUpfrontFee%22,%22Support%22,%22Upfront%22,%22Usage%22%5D,%22include%22:true,%22children%22:null%7D%5D&reportType=CostUsage&hasAmortized=true&excludeDiscounts=true&usageAs=usageQuantity&excludeCategorizedResources=false&excludeForecast=false) applied, Everything lines up perfectly for the last five months. However, there's a difference in the current month.

[image]

Is this because the amortization hasn't applied yet for the current month? If so, how can I get the correct amortized results?

I used this [source](https://www.wellarchitectedlabs.com/cost-optimization/cur_queries/query_help/#reserved-instance-and-savings-plan-example) as reference and Here's the Athena query I'm using:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(line_item_usage_start_date) AS year,
    MONTH(line_item_usage_start_date) AS month,
    DAY(line_item_usage_start_date) AS day,
    ROUND(SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN (line_item_line_item_type = 'SavingsPlanCoveredUsage') THEN COALESCE(savings_plan_savings_plan_effective_cost, 0)
            WHEN (line_item_line_item_type = 'SavingsPlanRecurringFee') THEN COALESCE(savings_plan_total_commitment_to_date - savings_plan_used_commitment, 0)
            WHEN (line_item_line_item_type = 'SavingsPlanNegation') THEN 0
            WHEN (line_item_line_item_type = 'SavingsPlanUpfrontFee') THEN 0
            WHEN (line_item_line_item_type = 'DiscountedUsage') THEN COALESCE(reservation_effective_cost, 0)
            WHEN (line_item_line_item_type = 'RIFee') THEN COALESCE(reservation_unused_amortized_upfront_fee_for_billing_period + reservation_unused_recurring_fee, 0) 
            WHEN (line_item_line_item_type = 'Fee') THEN 0
            ELSE COALESCE(line_item_unblended_cost, 0)
        END
    ), 2) AS amortized_cost
FROM "my_cur_report"
WHERE 
    line_item_line_item_type NOT IN ('Credit') AND
    DATE(line_item_usage_start_date) >= DATE('2023-10-01')
    AND DATE(line_item_usage_start_date) <= DATE('2023-10-01')
    AND line_item_usage_account_id = 'my_acc_id'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1,2, 3;
```

Any thoughts on addressing this current month difference would be appreciated. Thanks!